# Postgres database setting to allow ddl generation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two Postgres databases, one for Dev and one for Prod. I also have a Java/Hibernate application that has the following:

**persistence.xml**

```
  <persistence-unit name="pims">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/pims</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <!-- For JBoss / Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <!-- For Glassfish / Toplink -->
        <property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

**Problem**

When the JBoss server starts in the Prod environment, it creates the new tables as expected. But when it starts in the DEV environment (same code), it does not create the new tables.

This makes me think there is some setting on the database that prevents the creation of the new tables.

**Question**

Is there any config on the database that will prevent JPA/Hibernate from creating the new tables?

**More Info:**

Java 1.7
Struts 1
Hibernate 4.2.21.Final
PostgreSQL 8.0

Connection:

```
<jndi-name>jdbc/pims</jndi-name>
<connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pims</connection-url>
<driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
<user-name>postgres</user-name>
```

Users:

DEV

[image]

PROD

[image]

Comment: Does db user has enough permissions to create new tables? Can you on verbose output in spritng to see if additional information is available?

Comment: I just noticed that the `persistence.xml` is not in the module where the entities are, so I don't think it is being applied. But this does not explain why in PROD tables are created and not in DEV.